# Node-red UI builder with react frontend

Tags: reactjs, node-red

I was trying to get node-red data to a react frontend using the node-red ui builder. So I've created the example on the [node-red ui builder wiki](https://github.com/TotallyInformation/node-red-contrib-uibuilder/wiki/Example:-ReactJS) . After creating that example I'm facing the following issue when launching the created react-app.

ReferenceError: io is not defined
ioSetup
http://localhost:3003/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:6360:7

```
  6357 |     }
  6358 |   }
  6359 | };
> 6360 | self.socket = io(self.ioNamespace, self.socketOptions); // eslint-disable-line block-scoped-var
       | ^  6361 | 
  6362 | /** When the socket is connected - set ioConnected flag and reset connect timer  */
  6363 |
```

I have installed socket.io and tried adding `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` to index.html as well.Have anyone got lucky with this example without these issues?

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using a 5.0.x version of `uibuilder`?  If so, I believe there is an extra step required to include the socketio vendor library -- so the example _may_ be out of date.